# How can I pass STDin to IRB without it exiting after processing this input?

Tags: ruby, pipe, stdin, irb

I'm using a short bash script to help me test an implementation of linked lists in ruby for class.  I know about rspec and unit testing, and I'm certain they're better options for what I'm trying to do, but I was able to figure out this command

```
echo "require './nodes'" | irb
```

The output afterwards is

```
Switch to inspect mode.
require './nodes'
true
```

Technically a success, but the irb process ends there.  So I tried

```
echo "require './nodes'" | irb --noinspect
```

Which gave me

```
Switch to non inspect mode.
require './nodes'
true
```

And it again exits the irb process.

I'm just trying to make my workflow a little bit more convenient, as I like to use irb to test my files by poking around at them and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple script, the code below will land you into the `irb` shell with the 'nodes' gem included. If you are using Ruby 1.8.x then you'll need to add `require 'rubygems'` before requiring nodes gem

```
#!/path/to/ruby -w

require 'irb'
require 'nodes'
IRB.start
```

Comment: Thanks!  Did the trick.  Gives lots of warnings about assigned but unused variables, which must be from IRB.  Any way to quiet those warnings?  It works, but it would be even better without those messages.

Comment: try removing the `-w` from the shebang line.

Comment: d'oh, knew I should have looked that up

Comment: For one-liner command fans seeking to avoid extra files and scripts, simply running `ruby -r irb -r nodes -e "IRB.start"` could be equivalent.  Ends up with an interactive `irb` shell.