# automatic save and reload ruby objects between irb sessions

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling, yaml, irb

It is convenient that `irb` can save my execution history, accessible later via CTRL-R lookups.

Question, using my `.irbrc` or otherwise, is there a way to have `irb` save (at exit, or after every command) the state of objects, variables, classes, methods etc. that I've defined in interactive mode, and have them automatically reload next time I start irb?

One itch this would scratch is being able to **require** gems installed during an active irb session.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776230/how-can-i-pass-stdin-to-irb-without-it-exiting-after-processing-this-input/12777239#12777239, have a look at my answer. It will certainly stop the one itch of requiring gems :)

Comment: @Anand That doesn't solve the `LoadError: no such file to load -- roo` when 1. Start `irb`, do lots of stuff.  2. Weeks later, in a separate terminal: `gem install roo` 3. Back in the old unrestarted `irb` session, try `require "roo"` .  I didn't want to elaborate in the question as it is merely a digression :)